# How to design the tap panel like below link and image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to design a tab panel like below(from link https://erezeki.my/ms/how-it-works-my/) but i dont know how to set the tab header to follow the width of the pane and how to set the outer bolder:

Problem:
1. How to make the tab head width full and set the border like in the link.

What I had done so far
[image]

Source code:

```js
/*---Tab Js --*/
$("#simple-design-tab a").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
});
```

```css
/*----------------Icon Tab style----*/
.tab .nav-tabs{
  background: #ffffff;
}
.tab .nav-tabs li{
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.tab .nav-tabs li a{
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #464545;
  background: rgb(147, 147, 147);
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: ;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border:0px solid #e7ecea;
  transition:ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.tab .nav-tabs li a:hover{
  color: #464545;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.tab .nav-tabs li a i{
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.tab .nav-tabs li.active a,
.tab .nav-tabs li.active a:hover{
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #464545;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #eb1e1e;
}
.tab .tab-content{
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #707c88;
  font-family:'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 10px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 990px){
  .tab .nav-tabs li a{ padding: 15px 10px; }
  .tab .tab-content{ padding: 20px 25px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .tab .nav-tabs li a{ padding: 15px 5px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
  .tab .nav-tabs li{ width:100%; }
}
```

```html
<section class="tab-sec">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="tab tool-tab" role="tabpanel" style="border:1px solid #ddd;">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#Section1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tugasan Digital Mikro</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Kerja Digital</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Kerja Bukan Digital</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content tabs" id="home">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="Section1">
            <p>Tugasan atau kerja yang tidak memerlukan kemahiran teknikal ICT seperti menjalankan kaji selidik menggunakan borang pertanyaan, menjalankan tugasan dan perkhidmatan domestik, dimana tugasan ini diberikan secara atas talian, tetapi tugasan itu perlu dilakukan di luar rangkuman atas talian.</p>
            <br>Contol tugasan Kerja Bukan Digital adalah: –
            <br>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section2">
            <h3>Section 2</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla interdum sed diam ac fermentum. Mauris nec pellentesque neque. Cras nec diam euismod, congue sapien eu, fermentum libero. Vestibulum quis sem.</p>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section3">
            <h3>Section 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla interdum sed diam ac fermentum. Mauris nec pellentesque neque. Cras nec diam euismod, congue sapien eu, fermentum libero. Vestibulum quis sem.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- Tab section End -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `border-top` and active border using `box-shadow` and adjust the font-size according the screen

working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bbze50sv/1/)

```js
/*---Tab Js --*/
$("#simple-design-tab a").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
});
```

```css
/*----------------Icon Tab style----*/
.tab .nav-tabs{
  background: #ffffff;
}
.tab .nav-tabs li{
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
  width:1%;
}
.tab .nav-tabs li a{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #464545;
  background: rgb(147, 147, 147);
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: ;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;  
  transition:ease-in-out 0.5s;
  text-align:center;
}
.tab .nav-tabs li a:hover{
  color: #464545;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.tab .nav-tabs li a i{
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.tab .nav-tabs li.active a,
.tab .nav-tabs li.active a:hover{
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #464545;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0px #eb1e1e inset;
}
.tab .tab-content{
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #707c88;
  font-family:'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 10px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 990px){
  .tab .nav-tabs li a{ padding: 15px 10px; }
  .tab .tab-content{ padding: 20px 25px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .tab .nav-tabs li a{ padding: 15px 5px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
  .tab .nav-tabs li{ width:100%; }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="tab-sec">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="tab tool-tab" role="tabpanel" style="border:1px solid #ddd;">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#Section1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tugasan Digital Mikro</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Kerja Digital</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Kerja Bukan Digital</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content tabs" id="home">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="Section1">
            <p>Tugasan atau kerja yang tidak memerlukan kemahiran teknikal ICT seperti menjalankan kaji selidik menggunakan borang pertanyaan, menjalankan tugasan dan perkhidmatan domestik, dimana tugasan ini diberikan secara atas talian, tetapi tugasan itu perlu dilakukan di luar rangkuman atas talian.</p>
            <br>Contol tugasan Kerja Bukan Digital adalah: –
            <br>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section2">
            <h3>Section 2</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla interdum sed diam ac fermentum. Mauris nec pellentesque neque. Cras nec diam euismod, congue sapien eu, fermentum libero. Vestibulum quis sem.</p>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section3">
            <h3>Section 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla interdum sed diam ac fermentum. Mauris nec pellentesque neque. Cras nec diam euismod, congue sapien eu, fermentum libero. Vestibulum quis sem.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- Tab section End -->
```

Comment: tq very much... but do you know how to make it responsive like the tab in the link...when the screen become smaller the tab go down

Comment: Adjust font-size of link in small screen.. updated [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bbze50sv/2/)